# Page not found - when trying to view installed CakePHP instance

Tags: php, cakephp, frameworks, cakephp-2.0, cpanel

I have borrowed my friends hosting account to be able to work with CakePHP online.

He already had WordPress installed in the root directory so I installed a fresh copy of CakePHP in a sub folder using Softaculous from the cPanel. I got a response for a successful installation and checked the contents of the folder via FTP to make sure all the CakePHP folder structure is there in my sub folder including database config values that correspond to the server database. And it all seems fine.

But when I go to the URL 'www.site.com/subfolder' I get the WordPress template from my friends site with the message

```
'404 - Page Not Found
The page you are trying to access does not exist!'
```

What changes do I need to make to be able to view and work with my CakePHP instance ? :\ Please help

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it could be something wrong with the .htaccess file in the root folder.  It may be set to intercept all traffic and is routing you away from Cake before it get's a chance.